# How can load models image with django in css

Tags: python, html, css, django, model

I'm working on my blog website
I want use my post's image in my post page
for example my post list has some posts and when the user click in my post card Navigate to post page and this page i want show the post image in the background
I know what can do for load image in html I know use

```
 /static/img/.../
```

But I want load image in css like this

```
Background-image : url('')
```

I tried this code but don't work :

```
background-image: url('{{ MEDIA_URL }}/post_image/{{ post.image_url }}');
```

You know what can i do for this

paye attention I import my image from my media folder

Comment: You can set this part of css in your template in tag `<style>`

Comment: Nice,thats true but I'm carious for this how can load in css